# Which one is correct "Response surface method aid/aids efficient optimization"?

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct:

> Response surface method *aid* efficient optimization

or

> Response surface method *aids* efficient optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "method" is a singular noun, the first is less incorrect. But the noun phrase "response surface method" requires a determiner, so unless they are part of a larger sentence that provides such, they are both incorrect.

Comment: which verb is better than aid in this sentences? can you write it in better way

Comment: Method is singular, so goes with aids.  Don't you mean the second sentence is less incorrect?  It looks like maybe a typo.

Answer (score 0):

> Response surface method aids efficient optimization **<--- is correct!**

The reason is due to the fact that "Response surface method" is a [third-person singular noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third-person_singular). The same applies for third person pronouns (he, she, it).

If you were talking about "Response surface method**s**" the first sentence would have been correct.
Example:

> Response surface method**s** aid efficient optimization